# SQL Aggregate Over Date Range

Tags: sql, window, aggregation

Whoever answers this thank you so, so much!

Here's a little snippet of my data:

```
DATE          Score  Multiplier  Weighting
2022-01-05      3       4           7      
2022-01-05      4       7           8      
2022-01-06      5       2           4      
2022-01-06      3       4           7      
2022-01-06      4       7           8    
2022-01-07      5       2           4
```

Each row of this data is when something "happened" and multiple events occur during the same day.

What I need to do is take the rolling average of this data over the past 3 months.

So for ONLY 2022-01-05, my weighted average (called ADJUSTED) would be:

```
DATE                 ADJUSTED
2022-01-05    [(3*4) + (4*7)]/(7+8)
```

Except I need to do this over the previous 3 months (so on Jan 5, 2022, I'd need the rolling weighted average -- using the "Weighting" column -- over the preceding 3 months; can also use previous 90 days if that makes it easier).

Not sure if this is a clear enough description, but would appreciate any help.

Thank you!

Comment: How you tried to solve this?

Comment: Could you please provide an example for what you expect from multiple months/days? not sure I understood

Comment: "sql" is a standard, but each database vendor has different implementation of that standard - so **to answer this in syntax that will work for you**, we need to know what database you actually use. edit the tags please and include the dbms type.

Answer (score 0):

IF I have interpreted this correctly I believe a GROUP BY query will meet the need:

**sample data**

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   DATE       DATE  NOT NULL
  ,Score      INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Multiplier INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Weighting  INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable(DATE,Score,Multiplier,Weighting) VALUES ('2022-01-05',3,4,7);
INSERT INTO mytable(DATE,Score,Multiplier,Weighting) VALUES ('2022-01-05',4,7,8);
INSERT INTO mytable(DATE,Score,Multiplier,Weighting) VALUES ('2022-01-06',5,2,4);
INSERT INTO mytable(DATE,Score,Multiplier,Weighting) VALUES ('2022-01-06',3,4,7);
INSERT INTO mytable(DATE,Score,Multiplier,Weighting) VALUES ('2022-01-06',4,7,8);
INSERT INTO mytable(DATE,Score,Multiplier,Weighting) VALUES ('2022-01-07',5,2,4);
```

**query**

```
select
      date
    , sum(score)                                                    sum_score
    , sum(multiplier)                                               sum_multiplier
    , sum(weighting)                                                sum_weight
    , (sum(score)*1.0 + sum(multiplier)*1.0) / (sum(weighting)*1.0) ADJUSTED
from mytable
group by date
```

**result**

```
+------------+-----------+----------------+------------+-------------------+
|    date    | sum_score | sum_multiplier | sum_weight |     ADJUSTED      |
+------------+-----------+----------------+------------+-------------------+
| 2022-01-05 |         7 |             11 |         15 | 1.200000000000000 |
| 2022-01-06 |        12 |             13 |         19 | 1.315789473684210 |
| 2022-01-07 |         5 |              2 |          4 | 1.750000000000000 |
+------------+-----------+----------------+------------+-------------------+
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7c120d161f3d0ff45eb3dde3d9b5e50d)*

Note: I have not attempted to avoid possible divide by 0 or any NULL value problems in the query ablove